# error : *void is not public in *class; cannot be accessed error from outside package

Tags: java, jar, package

I have a jar library called `Ullman`. This jar containing 1 class named `ullman`. I tried to access a void from that class, when I just run the program, its working, but when I try to <kbd>Clean and Build</kbd> it I got the following error:

```
error: match(ArrayList<int[][]>,int[][],ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>,ArrayList<String>,ArrayList<Integer>) is not public in Ullman; cannot be accessed from outside package
    u.match(matrixgraph, matrixq, nodegraph, nodequery, nocandidategraph);
```

This is my code for importing that class :

```
import ullman.Ullman;
public class Gui extends javax.swing.JFrame {
   int max_frag;
   int ratio;
   public Ullman u=new Ullman();
........
```

and then I got an error when I try to access void from this GUI class
examples code when call the void

```
u=new Ullman();
u.match(matrixgraph, matrixq, nodegraph, nodequery, nocandidategraph);
```

How can I fix it?

The following is the `match` method in `ullman` class:

```
public void match(ArrayList<int[][]> matrixgraph, int[][] matrixquery, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> nodegraph, ArrayList<String> nodequery, ArrayList<Integer> nocandidate) {
    answer.clear();
    matrixq=matrixquery;
    for (int i = 0; i < matrixgraph.size(); i++) {
        int [][]matrixsmile=matrixgraph.get(i);
        matrixg=new int[matrixsmile.length-1][matrixsmile.length-1];
        for(int x=0;x<matrixg.length;x++){
            for(int y=0;y<matrixg.length;y++){
                matrixg[x][y]=matrixsmile[x][y];
            }
        }
        matrix_query_graph = new int[matrixq.length][matrixg[0].length];
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix_query_graph.length; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < matrix_query_graph[0].length; k++) {
                matrix_query_graph[j][k] = 0;
            }
        }

        // adjacency matrix M
        ArrayList<String>nodeq = nodequery;
        ArrayList<String>nodeg = nodegraph.get(i);
        for(int m=0;m<nodeq.size();m++){
            for(int n=0;n<nodeg.size();n++){
                if (nodeq.get(m).equals(nodeg.get(n))) {
                    matrix_query_graph[m][n] = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        if (subgraphMatching(matrixq, matrixg, matrix_query_graph)) {
            answer.add(nocandidate.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the method signature for `match()`.  Also, is your `Ullman` class public?  If not, it cannot be used outside of it's own package.

Comment: its already there. yes, the ullman class is already public. now im suspected it can't acces that method in class at other package from jar library. but why? im confused, why i cant access method from class at package in jar library, but i can access a method from other class in different package in 1 project(not as jar libray).

Comment: Fixed formatting, grammar and typos for readability. Please try to improve the title and add more details.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is saying that method which you are trying to access is not public in your imported class.

```
error: match(ArrayList<int[][]>,int[][],ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>,ArrayList<String>,ArrayList<Integer>) is not public in Ullman; cannot be accessed from outside package
    u.match(matrixgraph, matrixq, nodegraph, nodequery, nocandidategraph);
```

Error clearly says that method cant be accessed outside Ullman package

So make that `match()` method in  `Ullman` package public and then you can access it.

Comment: how to make it public? i just try to add word "public" in the front of the void but it can't work too

Answer (score 0):

The output you are seeing says that `Ullman.match()` is `private` and you can't access it directly from your example code.  Specifically, the `match()` method is *package private*, which it means it can only be called by subclasses of `Ullman` *or* by other classes in the same package.

If you have access to the `Ullman` class you try making `match()` public.  If you *don't* have access to the source code and you *must* access this method directly then you can try subclassing `Ullman` and then add a helper method which calls `Ullman.match()` like this:

```
public class NewUllman extends Ullman {
    public void callMatch(ArrayList<int[][]> p1,int[][] p2, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> p3, ArrayList<String> p4, ArrayList<Integer> p5) {
        match(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5);
    }
}
```

Comment: how to make void match() public if i have access to the ullman class? i try too add "public" in front of it, but can't work

Comment: is this subclassing for ullman must i build it in Gui package? i try it but it showed error too "error: cannot find symbol
match(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5);
symbol:   method match(ArrayList<int[][]>,int[][],ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>,ArrayList<String>,ArrayList<Integer>)
location: class SubgraphIsomorphismTest

Comment: `but can't work` ... this doesn't help us help you.  Please clearly state what is happening.

Comment: i try too add "public" in front of "void match", but it still get error "cannot be accessed error from outside package"

Comment: This sounds to me like you are not including the modified code when you try to use the updated method.  Are you sure your modifications are making it into the JAR which is being used to build your project?

Comment: because this class ullman is not my ownself code, i put it in other package then build it to jar library for my project. which makes me confused is when i just run from netbeans the program is fine, but when i try to clean and build it, it showed error